# Sign in to AWS from a console application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Here is my situation:

- I am creating a very simple .Net Core console application for use within my organization.
- It performs one simple task - that is, it inserts a record into a DynamoDB table.
- This is a simple utility that is part of a larger process.
- Anyone who uses this console application should already have access to our AWS account
- The users of this application are all technical professionals who understand AWS (see above)

Here is my question:

**Is there a way that the console application can prompt the user for their AWS credentials, and log them in?**

It would then use the credentials to access the DynamoDB table.

I know this isn't ideal, but while the users are skilled, I don't want each new user to have to go through the trouble of creating a credentials file on their local machine.

I want to just give the executable to someone, and have it do whatever it needs to authenticate and run, without external setup.

Comment: I would say this is not great because user's should never be inputting their IAM credentials to anything that's not directly to AWS. Access keys are not to be shared, even with other systems. This is similar to the system requesting their private SSH key

Answer (score 0):

We use something called `tokenschleuder` for similar tasks. `tokenschleuder` is a small Python tool (based on https://github.com/argais/aws_cli_adfs) which runs in background.
On start, it authenticates the user and starts a temporary AWS session with STS. Effectively, the tool generates temporary credentials for the AWS session and saves them in `.aws/credentials`. Thus all AWS SDKs have actual credentials for AWS operations.